# "maple tree" or "maple"?

Tags: terminology

Is it correct to say *maple tree*, or would *maple* be both correct and enough to mean a tree (not just its fruit)?

Comment: The botanical term for the fruit of the maple is samara. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samara_%28fruit%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *maple* is used to mean the tree. The definition given by the NOAD is "a tree or shrub with lobed leaves, winged fruits, and colorful autumn foliage, grown as an ornamental or for its timber or syrupy sap."

The word origin is from Old English *mapel*, which is the first element of *mapeltrēow*, *mapulder* ("maple tree"), used as an independent word from Middle English onward.

Comment: This leads us to ask the following question: What is the name of the maple fruits?

Comment: The winged fruits of the maple tree are generally referred to as "keys", at least here in Canada

Comment: The word "tree" is nearly always optional after kinds of tree, but for some kinds of tree it is pragmatically more often required. So for example, without context "three apples" would mean the fruit; but if we are planning a garden we can say "I'm going to put three apples there" and unambiguously mean the tree.

Comment: The NOAD reports that one of the meaning of key is "the dry winged fruit of an ash, maple, or sycamore maple, typically growing in bunches; a samara." I am not sure if in American English _keys_ would be used to refer to maple fruits when they are not dry.

Comment: In some contexts, the names of trees by themselves refer to pieces of wood from those trees. In contexts dealing with both trees and lumber, _tree_ might be necessary to specify such.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: in AmE, _key_ can be used to refer to the winged fruit thing whether it is dry on the ground, still attached to the tree, or spinning in the air in between.

Answer (score 4):

Maple doesn't refer to the fruit (unlike say an apple tree) since the main product of the maple is the sap or products made from it. If you eat a "maple tart" or "maple cookie" it will taste (at least in theory) like the concentrated sap, not the tree itself. The adjective doesn't imply "maple tree". That said, "a maple" is unambiguously a maple tree. Same for "an elm", "an oak", and other trees whose main product is not the fruit. "An apple" could mean an apple tree but only in highly specific contexts, eg "He looked along the drive, admiring the trees - several elms, an apple, and three maples."

Finally, for completeness, you might say "a maple" to mean "a maple one" such as "what flavour donut should I get you? A maple?" or "We were looking at flooring options and we've settled on a nice maple." But that's the adjective at work again.

Comment: Nice answer; great examples.